# Problems with duplicated events when connecting Google Calendar and Google Sheet using AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I successfully integrated GCalendar to Gsheet for creating events. After a Google Form submission, the App Script sends an invitation to my calendar and my guest calendar.

I'm having problems with the automation and the duplicated entries. The script doesn't run when a new row appears - tried both on edit and on form submission -, and when I force it to run, it reschedules ALL the past events.

Here my code

```
function CreateEvent() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('functionSheet');
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('name@email.com');
  var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var count = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:N"+lr+"").getValues();

    for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {

      var shift = count[x];

      var summary = shift[2];
      var startTime = shift[7];
      var endTime = shift[8];
      var guests = shift[1];
      var description = shift[3];
      var location = shift[5];   
      var event = {
          'location': location,
          'description': description,
          'guests':guests +',',
          'sendInvites': 'True',
      }

      eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event)
  }


}
```

I'm looking for a solution to improve my script so that it runs every time a new submission has been done AND do not send invitation based on old entries (previous rows).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to use onFormSubmit (a problems to resolve) AND you need to use [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) so that you can limit the processing to only the row that was submitted rather than all of the rows (which is what happens at present).

Comment: I've added a section in my answer covering installation of the trigger. Let me know if you need more information, or if this fails.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating calendar events based on Form responses from a Google Form. When your code runs, it is creating events for all the responses and not limited to the most recent response.

The actions to resolve this are two-fold:

1. trigger the function by using the installable trigger `onFormSubmit.
2. use [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) to capture the form response values, and update the calendar based on those values.

Note: your function is now called `CreateEvent(e)`. The `e` attribute will automatically give you access to the Event Objects.

The following code is untested, but it indicates the approach to be taken.

`

---

```
function CreateEvent(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // DEBUG

  // identify Calendar
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('<insert id >');

  // get the response data
  var summary = e.values[2];
  var startTime = e.values[7];
  var endTime = e.values[8];
  var guests = e.values[1];
  var description = e.values[3];
  var location = e.values[5];   
  var event = {
    'location': location,
    'description': description,
    'guests':guests +',',
    'sendInvites': 'True',
  }

  // create the event.
  eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event)


}
```

---

**onFormSubmit**

It is important that you trigger your function with the installable trigger `onFormSubmit`. Refer to the documentation for [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) for a set-by-step "how-to" explanation.

Your screen should look something like this when you have completed the setup.

Note that the function name (`CreateEvent`) does NOT indicate that you are using Event Objects - this is OK - the trigger is just picking up the basic name. BUT it is extremely important that your function is actually called `CreateEvent(e)` so that it can access the Event Objects.

---

[image]